# C# does not convert Number with int.TryParse

Tags: c#, integer, tryparse

This is my code, I am currently using Process to receiving angle values in degrees from my Arduino, which uses a MPU6050 for reading said values.

The following code should receive the datastream from the Serial Port:

```
string dataString = serialPort.ReadLine();
var dataBlocks = dataString.Split(',');
if (dataBlocks.Length < 3)
{
  Debug.LogWarning("Invalid data received");
  return; 
}

int angleX, angleY, angleZ;
if (!int.TryParse(dataBlocks[0], out angleX))
{
   Debug.LogWarning("Failed to parse angleX. RawData: " + dataBlocks[0]);
   return;
}
```

TryParse fails to parse the angle.

"Failed to parse angleX. RawData: 174.0"

As the error message points out, the raw data that was transmitted over the serial interface was 174.0.

Is the error related to using dot and commas for decimal seperation?

Comment: You have a floating point number and trying to parse to an integer (not a number).

Comment: [Integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) don't have decimal places.

Comment: Try `float.TryParse`, `double.TryParse` or `decimal.TryParse`, depending on which kind of number you are trying to work with.  You can't squish `174.0` into an integer directly

Comment: To clarify, `.` is used here as a decimal separator? I know some cultures use it to separate groups of three digits, for which purpose American English uses `,`.

Comment: I did actually thought that the decimal point was there because i was outputting it.
Otherwise, my Arduino sends an int over the Serial Bus, therefore i didnt thought it could come from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a decimal separator in your value. This suggests it is not an integer but actually a decimal (or real) value.

You should use `decimal.TryParse()` or `double.TryParse()` rather than int.TryParse() then cast the result to int.

```
string val = "17.0";

decimal d = 0;
int i = 0;

if (!decimal.TryParse(val, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out d))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not a decimal");
}
else
{
    i = (int)d;
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```